# How do I fetch and change tinyint values from phpmyadmin and change their values in php

Tags: mysql

I've set some flags using tiny int in my database and I want to retrieve them, check their values and change them accordingly. How can I do that?

db_connect.php:-

```
  <?php

    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbname =  'eden';
    $dbuser =  'root';
    $dbpass =  '';

    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);


   if(!$conn)
   {
    die("Connection Failed");
    }
    mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname);
    ?>

 <?php
   if ($row['S_status']==1)
   {
    echo "Selection Done";
    $row['D_status']=1;
    }
  ?>
```

Table structure:-
info_id(int)
Enrol_id(varchar)
ES_name(varchar)
S_status(tinyint)
D_status(tinyint)

Comment: You want to change their values into DB or just in your PHP script for future use? And how that is connected with PHPMyAdmin as this is just a web based database client?

Comment: I want to change the values in the database

Comment: S_status and D_status are diffrenent columns or is a just spell error?

Comment: If E_status is 1 the D_status should be changed to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need PHP for that, just SQL:

```
UPDATE yourTable SET D_status = 1 WHERE S_status = 1;
```

You can run this statement directly into PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: `if ($row['S_status']==1) {
     echo "Selection Done";
     $query = "UPDATE info_enrol_student SET S_status = 0 WHERE S_status = 1";
     $res = mysqli_query($conn,$ins);
     if (!$res) {
      echo "ERROR";
     }
    }`

Comment: No, this SQL statement will update all S statuses into the table from 1 to 0. And above you are talking about two columns (D and S), here you have only S, I'm confused.

Comment: The above comment is just demo, I am changing the values to 0 if its is 1

Comment: Can you help me with the sql statement

Comment: You have it above. If you want something different, update your answer as is not so clear what you want then.

Comment: I tried the above answer but tit does not change any field of the database

Comment: paste your table structure here (in your question body).